# Combining Kafka Events that are produced in very distinct moments in time using Kafka Streams

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

Before I start, it's important to mention that I'm new to Kafka Streams and I'm not a Java programmer. All I know is from reading lots of articles in the past few days and going through some examples from Kafka Tutorial.

I have a requirement to combine events that come in pretty distinct moments in time. I might receive event X today and event Y 3 days later. But I should only produce a new Z event *after* I've received X and Y.

Therefore, I'm looking for some advice in terms of wether Kafka Streams (or any other Kafka-relate tool) would have an easy way to deal with my requirement without involving lots of custom code. I've looked into time-bound windowing techniques but it doesn't look like they are a fit for my issue, as it would be really hard to guess what the size of window.

I've read a ton these past few days and I'm getting to the conclusion I will end up having to do all the combinations "by hand", but I wonder if I'm missing something since I'm new to this whole ecosystem. Kafka Streams seems awesome for lots of other requirements we have here, just struggling to see if I can add that this particular scenario under the "kafka streams" umbrella or treat it as a fully separate custom development.

Comment: Is there a particular field in the record that designates "event Y" as "the end" or even that it should "correspond" to "event X"? Sounds like you'll need a Ktable, at the very least, keyed on a common value, then emit new events when your statestore has a matching key and your "end flag" is being processed

Comment: @OneCricketeer not exactly a field in the record, more of a "rule" to be store somewhere (like an external DB) that would say "only emit Z after you receive X and Y"

Comment: You'll still need some persistence layer that is able to hold at least one event indefinitely. Kafka Streams can be used if you have very tolerant infrastructure, but I tend to lean towards more stable database servers in this case. As you receive/upsert data, you need to check for existing records that match your ruleset; on a match, you generate a producer-record

Comment: @OneCricketeer yeah, that's kind of the conclusion I was getting to, good to know I'm not that far off. Thank you for your inputs!